# Android: broadcast receiver not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have the following class for connection listener

```
public class connectionListener{
    public ConnectivityManager conMgr;
    public htmlParserListener vystrahyListener;
    public htmlParserListener podmienkyListener;
    private ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    public connectionListener(ConnectivityManager conMgr, htmlParserListener vystrahyListener, htmlParserListener podmienkyListener){
        this.conMgr = conMgr;
        this.vystrahyListener = vystrahyListener;
        this.podmienkyListener = podmienkyListener;
    }

    private class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            System.out.println("connected");
        }
    }
    public synchronized void startListening(Context context) {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
            System.out.println("start");
        }
    }
```

I instantiate it with this code (from MainActivity):

```
    connectionListener conLst = new connectionListener(conMgr, vystrahyListener, podmienkyListener);
    conLst.startListening(this);
```

However I am getting "start" at output so startListening method works but I dont get "connected" when I disable or enable mobile data. So it looks like my BroadcastReceiver is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in forward

Comment: Have you put <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> permission in manifest.

Comment: yes, I have put it there

Comment: post your manifest or check your manifest Receiver intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont get "connected" when I disable or enable mobile data.

That is correct. This `Broadcast` is not triggered when mobile data is enabled or disabled but only when the network connectivity changes.

> So it looks like my BroadcastReceiver is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Your `BroadcastReceiver` is working correctly. However, you expect the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` `Broadcast` to be triggered at an event where it isn't triggered.

Note: there exists no (other) `Broadcast` which is sent by the system when the enabled state of mobile data is changed. You also have no option to register a `Listener` for this change.

Comment: To explain ... I am trying to make something like facebook messenger refresh method. When you start app without internet it says you dont have connection but as soon as I turn on mobile data or wifi etc. It says connecting. So I want to do the same thing but I just need to run one asynctask after connection is established ... can you suggest a way to do this efectively (best without using services)?

Comment: You can use the method from your original question. Your BroadcastReceiver will then be called when a connectivity change occurs. This does not occur if you toggle mobile data while you're already connected, e.g., via Wi-Fi. Please expect a delay between the connectivity change and your Receiver being called.